# Why only few logging are being sent to Azure Application insight through ServerTelemetryChannel?

Tags: azure, logging, azure-application-insights

This is my program in which I am using ServerTelemetryChannel because I read it is better than InMemoryChannel. But in this case only couple of logging are being sent to Azure Application Insight. Inside my `try` block I have a lot of logging and method calling which also contains logs. I have read the [documentation](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/blob/develop/BASE/src/ServerTelemetryChannel/ServerTelemetryChannel.cs) but it is not clear what values should I add, like in case of `MaxTelemetryBufferCapacity` property, what is the best value I can add here.

Secondly, this program will work as webjob. So according whats the best practice to add ServerTelemetryChannel logging. What all properties from `ServerTelemetryChannel` I should use?

```
public class Program
    {
        private static IServiceCollection services;

        private static IServiceProvider serviceProvider;
        private static ILogger<Program> logger;
        private static TelemetryClient telemetryClient;
  static void Main()
        {
            services = new ServiceCollection()
               .AddLogging(loggingBuilder => loggingBuilder
                   .AddFilter<Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights.ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider>("",
                       LogLevel.Trace))
               .AddSingleton(typeof(ITelemetryChannel), new ServerTelemetryChannel())
               .AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService(
                   ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApplicationInsightKey"]);

            serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
            logger = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
            telemetryClient = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<TelemetryClient>();

            using (telemetryClient.StartOperation<RequestTelemetry>("Program Name"))
            {
                logger.logInformation("Execution started")
                try
                {
                    ..Execution...
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    logger.logError(e.ToString())
                }
                finally
                {
                   logger.logInformation("Execution completed")
                   telemetryClient.Flush();
                }
            }
           
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not have to modify the `ServerTelemetryChannel` properties, the defaults are just fine. Also, `ServerTelemetryChannel` is the default so you do not need to add it manually.

Apart from the log level, there are some other factors that can cause telemetry to not appear. One is [sampling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/sampling) and the other one is not flushing the channel internal buffer so any telemetry still in the buffer is not send to the Azure backend upon closing the application. **Do keep in mind you need to wait for a short period of time after calling `Flush()` as this can take some time and is an async operation.**

In the code below sampling is disabled and the buffer is flushed correctly:

```cs
static void Main()
{
    services = new ServiceCollection()
        .AddLogging(loggingBuilder => loggingBuilder
            .AddFilter<Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights.ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider>("",
                LogLevel.Trace))
        .AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService((options) =>
        {
            options.InstrumentationKey = "xxxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxxx";
            options.EnableAdaptiveSampling = false;
        });

    serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    logger = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
    telemetryClient = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<TelemetryClient>();

    using (telemetryClient.StartOperation<RequestTelemetry>("Program Name"))
    {
        logger.LogTrace("Execution started");
        try
        {
                    
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            logger.LogError(e.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            logger.LogInformation("Execution completed");
        }
    }

    telemetryClient.Flush();
    Task.Delay(5000).Wait();
}
```